# Type '' could not be resolved, template type

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am a bit rusty with programming and couldn't find a solution on the web. 
I am creating a template class, and when using it I seem to be getting the error:

Type 'temp' could not be resolved

I have to tried to clean and rebuild, but it didn't help. Any advice is appreciated.

```
  /*
 * avlTREE.h
 *
 *  Created on: May 1, 2016
 *      Author: 
 */

#ifndef AVLTREE_H_
#define AVLTREE_H_
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>


class avlTreeException{};
class avlTreeExceptionInvalidInput : public avlTreeException{};

template <class temp>
class avlTREE{
public:
    temp* ptr;
}
#endif /* AVLTREE_H_ */
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of your template declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the missing semicolon, there is nothing inherently wrong with your template class.

```
template <class temp>
class avlTREE{
public:
    temp* ptr;
};

int main(){
  avlTREE<int> foo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after adding the semicolon I still have the same issue.

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis how are you instantiating the class?

Comment: By the way, are you sure a semicolon is essential? It seems that at my previous project which compiles there wasn't one after the template deceleration.

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis A semicolon at the end of a class deceleration is required.

Comment: I am so freaking stupid, I accidently put the semicolon after the template line and not at the end of the class. Thank you so much for answer my silly questions!